# Two Admin accounts for SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql, tcp, connection-string, administration

I have windows xp on two systems.On one machine i have installed sql server 2005 express.
now from the other machine which is on LAN with the first machine, i will access sql server to insert data via a .net application. my server instance is A-9.
i have created alias as : A-9-1. my connection string is :

conn.ConnectionString= "Data Source=A-9-1 ; Trusted_Connection =true ";  -- this is using windows authentication.my windows user name is Admin, without any password.

now, when i connect to sql server on machine 1, from the client machine, then error occurs saying: Login failed for A-9\Guest.

Can i not connect to sql as Administrator from the client machine also, i.e. using windows authentication. means, there would be two administrators for sql server. one is A-9\Admin on the server machine, and the other would be A-9-1\Admin on the client machine.
is this possible?

actually i want to give all privileges to the client machine user, for the sql database, he could create logins,users, databases, tables, insert data, give permissions and do everything.

also,

Comment: Is the client machine on the same network?  I'm assuming it is based on your other question where you say that they connect over the LAN.

Comment: yes sir, client machine is on LAN with the server machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can setup as many logins as you want that have any number of permissions in SQL Server. This includes owner rights on a database.

2) If you want to give access to **ANY** client machine, then add A-9\Guest as a login under Security for the database.  Then give them the appropriate rights.

Be aware that this will give anyone who connects to the server machine the rights that you specify for A-9\Guest.

3) There would not be a second admin called A-9-1\Admin.  Since it sounds like you are not using Active Directory on a Domain in your network, the server has no way to know what the user/login is of the client machine.  This is why you see the error: Login failed for **A-9\Guest**.  Also it sounds like A-9-1 is the name of the connection, but not the machine/domain.

In your scenario, you would be better off just using SQL Authentication and setting a username and password for the client machine to use for access.

**EDIT**

Some Active Directory Links:

**WARNING:  While setting up AD is not 'hard', it is a involving process that takes planning. ***

[AD Quick Start Set Up Guide](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/1474461/Active-Directory-Quick-Start--Set-Up-Guide.htm)

[Google Search for setting up active directory](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=setting+up+active+directory&aq=0&aqi=g4g-o1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.1,or.&fp=5e2b21bd614e0a97)

I still think you would be better off using SQL Authentication. :)

Comment: @Tony Abrams, Dear Sir, i dont want to create any new login, i have one windows login for sql server. i want to use that only for the client machine also, can i connect sql from the client machine using that windows authentication?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can only do that if you are using Active Directory and both computers are on the same Domain.  Active Directory allows you to share the logins on a Domain across many different computers.

Comment: @Tony Abrams, Also, sir , A-9-1 is the alias of the sql server instance.

Comment: @Tony Abrams ,sir can you refer me a link how to use active directory?

Comment: When you look at a login, there are two parts Domain\username. Without Active Directory, the domain is specific to each computer and uses an individual computer's name (as setup under system properties).

Comment: @Tony Abrams, sir, is creating alias for sql server instance necessary, for connecting to sql server from a client computer.

Comment: @Tony Abrams, sir, my sql server name is A-9, alias for sql server is A-9-1,now when i connect to sql server from the same machine on which sql is installed, but by specifying alias in the "Connect to Server" dialog , then it does not connects, giving network related instance error. why so? can i not connect to sql on the same machines from the same machine using the alias name?

Comment: It's not necessary.  You should be able to connect to it by using the Computer Name\SQl Instance Name  (EX:  A-9\MyServerName).  The alias does not affect the logins used for connecting in any way.  The alias just affects what name is used in connection strings.

Comment: The alias is mainly used for external (Remote) connections.  When on the machine with the SQL Server, you should use localhost.  Trying to connect with the alias locally will likely result in a loop-back attempt that will most likely fail.  Resulting in the network related instance error.

Comment: @Tony Abrams, sir, you have mentioned to add A-9\Guest under the logins, i am confused, that one login is already present in sql server by default as guest. so do i have to use that or i have to create a new login namely Guest

Comment: @Tony Abrams, Dear Sir, whats the difference between database server & database file. according to me when we create a database in SQL Server, then SQL Server generates an .mdf file for it. and all the database objects (tables, procedures) are added into that file only.so what would be the difference if a use mdf file or sql server, in both the cases the insertions and updations done would be updated in the .mdf file finally. the benefit of using sql server would be that: logins and user permissions can be used . would there be any other benefits also?

Comment: If it's already there then you just need to set the permissions for that login.

Comment: @Tony Abrams, sorry sir, there's no guest login, but a guest user is present in the databases under the users tab, they are : dbo, guest, INFORMATION_SCHEMA, sys.

Comment: You are correct in the fact that the mdf contains the mdf and the mdf is where the CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations occur. In basic terms, SQL Server gives you better/easier ability to control access to the file and allows for the creation of maintenance jobs (backups, pruning, etc).  There are more advanced things that it allows you to do, but they only matter if you are using/need them.  There is nothing wrong with using just a mdf file, unless your needs pass the use of the mdf file w/o SQL Server.

Comment: @Tony Abrams: sir, i need logins and permissions on the mdf file. in that case , it is necessary to use the Database server i guess , not only mdf file? and sir how to protect my mdf file from being stolen away and opened by others in their sql servers, in accordance with this question?

Comment: If it's a flat mdf file, then you have to limit access to the folder the file is located in. This is generally done by setting the security/permissions of the folder.

Comment: @Tony Abrams: if i limit access to the folder then will my .net application on the client machine be able to access the mdf file or not?

Comment: Depending on how the security/permissions are setup on the folder, you could disable the ability of the .net application to access the mdf.

Comment: Looks like I missed a question about dbo, guest, INFORMATION_SCHEMA, sys.  The Guest user would have to be given a login.

Comment: @Tony Abrams : then sir, whats the difference in using a database server for my application or database file? what shall i use ? you please suggest.

Comment: @Tony Abrams: i could give login to any user, not necessarily guest. isn't it?

Comment: You could give login to any user you wish, but it has to be a user that the client machine will/can connect with.  Because of the information I've heard (I.E. No Active Directory), any connection (across the LAN) will use the Guest account.

Comment: Due to the permission issues, I would say you should be using SQL Server.

Comment: @Tony Abrams : ok sir, so in the connection string i would give the login name. but sir, what is the use of logins in sql, i know that under one login we can create many users, but then also we have to give permissions individually to all users created under that login , so what is the use of logins then? and what about roles ? are they same as logins?

Comment: @Tony Abrams: in the case of roles, i know that on giving permission to a role, all the users under the role get that permission? so what about in the case of logins?

Comment: The login is a server level mapping (usually relating to a user account on the computer).  The user is a database level mapping (usually relating a login to a database).  A login can only have one user per database.

Comment: You are correct, the roles are just groupings of permissions. So that it's easier to assign multiple permissions to a user.

Comment: @Tony Abrams :thanks a lot sir for your awesome help, i am totally obliged & grateful to you.so in my .net application case,the application will run on 3 client machines on LAN, accessing sql server on a server machine,all with windows xp or 7,there would be 3 users-A,B,C,who would insert data into the sql database,so i would have to create ROLES instead of Logins,i guess?because the database is a single database,in which all 3 usersA,B,C will insert data.SO what should i create? 3 LOGINS,L1,L2,L3 with one user each under every login OR ONE SINGLE ROLE-ROLE1, with three users under that ROLE1

Comment: You can create one login (if login doesn't exist) and one user using the default role(s) (or a custom one(s) if you see fit).  Then you just need to be sure that the three clients all use that login to access the server and db. If all three connect using different logins, then you would need three different logins with three different users, but they could all use the same roles.

Comment: @Tony Abrams, i want all three users to access with different user ids and passwords. and what is the hierarchy of roles and logins and users, am totally confused among these three? is it as : Roles-->Logins-->>Users (meaning that, roles contain logins and logins contain users) OR is it: Logins-->Roles-->Users, OR no ROLES. are roles necessary? without them can we work?

Comment: @Tony Abrams, i want all three users to access with different user ids and passwords.so in this case , are logins needed ? can i only create a ROLE and 3 users in that ROLE. can users be created in role. and the role would access the sql database? can we work without logins?

Comment: It's typically Logins - > Users and Roles. The roles are then assigned to logins and users. One role can be assigned to multiple users.  Also you do not need to create new roles, there are several build in roles that generally get the job done.

Comment: You have to have logins. They control the access to the server.

Comment: @Tony Abrams: sir, when i create a login-aakash & user-aakashuser, then what are the by default roles which aakahuser would have?

Comment: @Tony Abrams:i got it sir, roles are like dbwriter , dbreader, denydatawriter, denydbaccess etc

Comment: @Tony Abrams: sir, when i create a login-aakash & user-aakashuser, then what are the by default roles which aakaShuser would have?

Comment: I believe by default roles given are just public.  You will need to add the dbwriter and dbreader roles to the user.

Comment: @Tony Abrams: Dear Sir, are you there?

Comment: @Tony Abrams ,hello sir, when do you come online?

Comment: Usually I'm in and out throughout the day.

Comment: @Tony Abrams: Good Morning Sir, how are you? sir i have posted a question but din't get a solution for it? you please have a look at it. would be a great help.the url is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040415/passing-data-between-3-windows-forms-in-visual-studio-using-c

Comment: @Tony Abrams, sir, we create logins with passwords, and then we create users under that logins, but can we give passwords for the users also?

Comment: Users are an 'abstraction' of the Logins.  Since the Logins are where you specify the passwords, the users 'carry' that password.  There is no way of creating a user with a password different then that of the login it uses.

Comment: @Tony Abrams: hello sir, how are you, i have a question at -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078754/change-data-source-dynamically-from-net-application-pass-to-connectiong-string   , please have a look at it, sir.