# passing data between 3 windows forms in visual studio using C#

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a windows application which has 3 forms : Form1,2,3. I want to send text of a textbox from `form2` to `form1` and then that same text from `form1` to `form3`, that is,

Text from `FORM2`-->`FORM1`-->`FORM3`

- Form 1, has 2 buttons , openform2, openform3.
- Form2 has a textbox form2_textbox, & a button send_to_form1_button
- Form3 has a textbox received_from_form1_textbox

Now,

- on clicking button `openform2` on `form1`, `Form2` opens,
- a string is entered in textbox `form2_textbox` of `Form2`,
- when button `form2_button` of this form is clicked, then I want `Form1` to receive this string value & stores it in a string `receivefromform2`,
- and then displays this string value on to `form3_textbox` of `Form3`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string receivefromForm2a;

    public Form1()
    { InitializeComponent(); }

    public void Method_Receive_From_Form2(string receivefromForm2)
    {
        receivefromForm2a = receivefromForm2;
        Form3 f3 = new Form3(receivefromForm2a);
    }

    private void openform3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();**----this line gives error:No overload for method Form3 takes 0 arguments**

            f3.Show();
        }

    private void OPENFORM2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string loginname = form2_textbox.Text;
    }

    //SENDING VALUE OF TEXTBOX ON FORM2 TO FORM1.

    private void send_to_form1_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Method_Receive_From_Form2(form2_textbox.Text);
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3(string receive_from_Form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        received_from_form1_textbox.Text = receive_from_Form1;
    }
}
```

This error occurs because in `form2` I have given argument for `form1` during object creation.
So what should I do? Is there any other way to do this or how do I remove this error?

When I include the `f3.Show()` in the method **Method_Receive_From_Form2** then there is no error. but this makes the `form3` load automatically without any button click. But I want `form3` to open by clicking the button on `form1`. And then the value to be shown in the textbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend a change from using constructors to using properties.  This will keep things properly 'contained' and it's pretty simple.

EX:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
   public String form1Text {get; set;}

   public Form3()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   public Form2()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       string loginname = form2_textbox.Text;
   }

   public String form2Text {get; set;}

   private void send_to_form1_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       form2Text = form2_textbox.Text;
       this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;
       this.Close();
   }
}
```

Then in form 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   string receivefromForm2a;

   public Form1()
   { InitializeComponent(); }       

    private void openform3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.form1Text = receivefromForm2a;
        f3.Show();
    }

private void OPENFORM2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    if(f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
    {
      receivefromForm2a = f2.form2Text; //New Property on Form2.
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create nonparametrized constructor for form3 like in form2:

`public Form3()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }`

This usually to create abstract methods in forms and/or delegates for updating textboxes and sharing data between forms. Or create some data holder.

Answer (score 1):

That error is thrown because Form3 has no default Constructor anymore since you defined one with a `string` parameter. you need to create a default Constructor like this `public Form3(){}`.

But Instead of doing all this mess you can handle events of you both forms. Like if Form1 is the main Form then something like this can be done:

In Form1

```
public string textFromForm2 = string.Empty;
private void openform3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
    f3.Controls["received_from_form1_textbox"].Text = textFromForm2 ;
    f3.Show();
}

private void OPENFORM2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    //I am binding the event to a handler which will save text
    //you should check for null for f2.Controls returned any thing or not, i am leaving it for now
    f2.Controls["send_to_form1_button"].Click += (s,e)=>{
                 txtFromForm2 = f2.Controls["form2_textbox"].Text;
          };
    f2.Show();
}
```

**Update**

if you don't want to use  Lambadas then  bind events like this:

First you will need a reference to the Form2 so declare in your class like this:

```
Form2 f2;
```

then bind the event (in place of the lambada i have given before)

```
f2.Controls["send_to_form1_button"].Click  += new Eventhandler(click_handler);
```

then somewhere in Form1 class:

```
protected void click_handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(f2 != null)
         txtFromForm2 = f2.Controls["form2_textbox"].Text;
}
```

similarly for Form3.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: dear sir, can you explain me the binding the event code, i dont know whats happening in it? i copied it in my code, but its giving syntax errors?

Comment: i have used Lambda and anonymous delegates to bind event.. if you are using .net 2.0 (Whre they are not supported) then you can do usual binding i have explained in my update

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: sir, my problem hasn't been solved yet, please tell me where to put this code which you have given, am confused totally, am not able to implement a simple process of sending a textbox text from Form2 to Form1 and then from Form1 to form3, FORM1 being the main parent form.

Comment: put this code in Form1. if you still have problems.. Give us your whole code we will see nd tell you what to modify.. (post your code here or on pastebin)

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro : sir, i have pasted the code above in my question itself. do i have to make changes in that also?

Comment: Here is your original code http://pastebin.com/E6X1NKnq and here is modified code http://pastebin.com/cCmfEDDP and here is the diff http://pastebin.com/diff.php?i=cCmfEDDP

Comment: @Shekhar Pro : sir, i have pasted the code below , please check it out.

Comment: @Shekhar Pro : sir , the new code url is : http://pastebin.com/knxpRKwc , please have a look

Comment: yeah your code is also correct.. now implement it. Good Luck :)

Comment: @Shekhar Pro: sir, i copied this code & pasted, but now form1 opens, but on clicking any of the buttons, nothing happens, neither form2 opens nor form3

Comment: are you even binding those event handlers to buttons. Do it in Forms Load event or simply Select the Button in Form Designer and Click on (Thunder) icon in Properties window and there select the Click event and from the Drop down select the respective Event handler.

Comment: @Shekhar Pro:sir, i went to Form1 design.cs and for openform2 button , i chose  Click event as openform2_Click , and for openform2 button , i chose  Click event as openform3_Click. but its not working. should i chose click_handler event but for which button then? and please tell whats the difference in choosing the event from the Thunder button and by double clicking on the button and then writing the code for the event.

Comment: @Shekhar Pro: dear sir, you forget all the old code, now my only new code is on url: pastebin.com/knxpRKwc , but its not working, when i click on openform2 , form2 opens, i type in the text , and click on the sendtoform1 button, then from the already opened Form1, which is the main form, which loads when the application starts , i clicked on the openform3 button , the Form3 opens , but the textbox is empty, according to me it should contain the value which i wrote in the textbox of form2.

Comment: come over on [facebook](http://facebook.com/samajshekhar) if you want to chat and sort this out.. these comments are not ment for that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Constructor which has an argument of type string in Form3.cs.

```
public Form3()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
public Form3(string text):this()
{
   this.txtName.text=text;
}
```

Comment: please explain this, and tell me that which code should i remove from my existing code? its not working sir?

Answer (score -2):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string receivefromForm2a;

    public Form1()
    { InitializeComponent(); }

    public void Method_Receive_From_Form2(string receivefromForm2)
    {
        receivefromForm2a = receivefromForm2;
        Form3 f3 = new Form3(receivefromForm2a);
    }

    private void openform2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void openform3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3(); //**----this line gives error:No overload for method Form3 takes 0 arguments**
        f3.Show();
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //SENDING VALUE OF TEXTBOX ON FORM2 TO FORM1.

    private void send_to_form1_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3(string receive_from_Form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        received_from_form1_textbox.Text = receive_from_Form1;
    }
}
```