# Update Database Table with tableAdapterTable command in C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, tableadapter

I have a C# form program in Visual Studio 2012 with built in database I'm trying to update. It's about customers and pizza orders.
I am able to add new Customers / PizzaOrders just fine, however when I try to do an update, I always get an error stateing "No overloaded method "methodName" takes 4 arguments."

Here is what I'm trying to use to update:

```
this.customerTableAdapter.UpdateCustomer(Name, Telephone, Original_CustomerID, CustomerID);
```

And here is the Visual Studio generated SQL to run this update:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Customer] SET [Name] = @Name, [Telephone] = @Telephone WHERE (([CustomerID] = @Original_CustomerID) AND ([Name] = @Original_Name) AND ([Telephone] = @Original_Telephone));
SELECT CustomerID, Name, Telephone FROM Customer WHERE (CustomerID = @CustomerID)
```

I figure I'm not putting the right variables in the command / not the right order.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: As per the error message it is obvious that the method you are trying to make use do not exist within your code class/ module. Are you certain that  the `UpdateCustomer` method expects the same number of parameters passed in? Did you debug to verify on which line the mentioned error is generated?

Comment: The error message is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854934/no-overload-for-method-form3-takes-0-arguments-c-sharp) SO query.

Comment: Yes, the error is coming from this.customerAdapter... and the SQL I posted is being implemented by UpdateCustomer

Comment: Glad, that you managed to solve it and get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The query generated by Visual Studio was making it match a column by every column in the row (Name, Telephone, and CustomerID) rather than just by matching the CustomerID.

Also make sure the data types being given to the query are of the same type that the columns have.