# change data source dynamically from .net application & pass to connectiong string

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, roles

My Visual Studio .NET application uses SQL Server 2005 Express.

It has to be installed on my customer's main server system & on two client computers.all with Windows XP or Vista or 7.

Now, every time when i install my application & SQL Server on my customers computers, I have to change the server name specified in the connection string, i.e. the DATA SOURCE.
Because, when I install SQL Server on customer's computer, then the server name is taken by SQL Server 2005 Express, as the computer name of the customer.

So, what's the solution for this?

1. Shall I change the computer name of the customer, to what i have specified in my connection string.
2. or , should i take the server name dynamically on runtime from the .net application and then pass it to the connection string.

Also, the same problem is for login? My .NET application would ask for the login & password from the customer, which would then be passed to the connection string & the application would connect to SQL Server. So, is this ok with security? if not, then what's the other solution to create logins of SQL Server from the .NET application dynamically.

Also, should i create APPLICATION ROLES for this purpose , i.e. for solving the login problem?

My connection string is : Data Source = A-9 (computer name) ; Trusted_Connection = true;

----------------------------------------------EDITED---------------------------------------

At my customer's place,'APP_SVR' is server machine name, he has 2 client
m/cs : C-1 & C-2. All 3 are simple home PCs on LAN, with Windows XP.

1.I will install SQL SERVER EXPRESS on 'APP_SVR'. While installation, 
  SQL SERVER automatically takes the server name as the computer name 
  on which it is installed , here it is 'APP_SVR'. 
  So , 'APP_SVR' will be the DATA SOURCE NAME in the conn. string.

2.I will install the .NET application on C-1,C-2.

3.Now, the application on C-1,C-2 will have to connect to SQL SERVER on 'APP_SVR'.
  For this,the applcn. needs DATA SOURCE NAME. So, I would take the data source name from
  users using C-1 & C-2, as a text input & then pass it to the connection string.
  The users would enter it as 'APP_SVR'.

Would this be fine with security issues ? or is there any other way?

Comment: Are all of these computers on the same network? And If so why does have to be SQL Server installed on all three machines?

Comment: @Tony Abrams : sir, that case is different, i have two customers, both of them have three computers each. now on one computer of both customers, i will install sql server.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to make sure. :)

Comment: @Tony Abrams : sir, i have updated my question, please check it out.

Comment: @Tony Abrams : Also, sir, when i run sqlcmd -L in the command prompt, on the client machine C-1 or C-2, then it shows the server name A-9 (my sql is installed on my machine named A-9). so can't this be used by my application i.e. my application fetches this name by some way and connects to sql server installed on the server 'APP_SVR'

Comment: Each SQL Server by default (to put it simply) broadcasts its existence, which can be picked up by sqlcmd. But i would never recommend that to be used to build a connection string. On one hand, it would only work as long as exactly one SQL Server exists on the network, on the other hand it opens up hundreds of security, performance and administration issues. So, please, don't do that :)

Comment: @oleschri, sir , please see my edited part of the question also

Comment: @sqlchild: I think I read the edited part ;) I just don't get why you would not want to write (manually or with some mini-setup-application) the server's hostname into the client's app.config file.

Comment: If you want to write a mini-setup-application that enumerates SQL Servers on the network, there is a sample for doing so here: http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=45

Comment: @oleschri, sir , please elaborate, i din't understand ? i will install sql only on APP_SVR. and then C-1, C-2 would run the exe file of my application to start using it. so , where is the role of client app.config file. i won't install visual studio anywhere. then what to do with app.config file

Comment: Please read the basics about configuration files here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(VS.80).aspx You have to install your someapp.exe together with a copy of the app.config named someapp.config to the client. Then you can adapt the someapp.config file to the customer's settings.

Comment: @oleschri, sir i have a question on :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114558/using-application-role-of-sql-server2005-express-in-multiple-forms-in-c/5114611#5114611

Comment: ... Hmm, why do I feel like Peppermint Patty today? ;)

Comment: @oleschri, thanks a lot for your help sir, sorry am disturbing you a lot, but being a beginner i need a lot of help, that's why am just being sticky

Comment: Never mind :)  I don't want to sound rude, but i think a good book from Microsoft Press might help you a lot. I can't give you a good recommendation though, since the ones I know are a bit outdated (.NET Framework 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the connection string is involved, oleschri is correct.  Your best option is to make use of an app.config file.  You will then have to change the connection string to point to the correct server by hand.  There is no real way of making this dynamically as you have no way of knowing the ip/name of the server machine from client to client until you see the environment.

As for the logins and connecting the application to SQL, this can be done the way you are suggesting.  With changing the connection string dynamically with the username and password provided by a user.

**Generally**, I handle this by creating a users table in my database.  This table would have usernames and password **to allow access to my program**.  The logins in SQL Server should be used **for limiting/securing access to the database itself**.  I generally create one login/user and all users then use this to access the database.  This helps to lock down access to the database while allowing you to provide security to access the application.  For this to work though, you will need to take the username/password from the user and check the database to see if it exists and is correct.  If so let them continue, if not keep them at the login screen and tell them that either the username and/or password is wrong.

Comment: When using (technically) one powerful login/user to SQL Server, one has to be careful that the credentials are (at least) not stored in clear text in a client application. This way anyone at the client pc could mess up the database e.g. with SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @oleschri, That's a good point to bring up. You should also make sure that the login only has the bare essential db roles to help mitigate client's fiddling with the db.

Answer (score 1):

I would definately go with alt 2, changing your customers computer names might make them, or their it-admins, pretty darn angry.

Comment: There is no way of 'dynamically' detecting the server name from inside of the .Net application.  You do not know what machine is the server (by name or ip).

Comment: Well there is the Environment.MachineName property, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx . Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: @Tony Abrams : dear sir, i have questions on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117029/logins-users-permissions-in-sql-express-2005-with-diagram-flowchart   ,    &     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125140/abstract-actual-login-name-from-client-users-provide-them-a-username-under-that    .    please look them out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your client application is some kind of WinForms application the connection string should reside inside the application's app.config file and should be set to the correct value when installing it.

Having the connection string in the app.config helps admin to easily update the client when server names or database names change over time.

- [MSDN: Storing and Retrieving Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28VS.80%29.aspx)

If you want to use Integrated Windows Security (the currently logged on Domain User) you can put the users to be authorized into a group and authorize this group in SQL Server accordingly. You also have to specify `Integrated Security=True` in your connection string.

- [MSDN: ConnectionString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28VS.71%29.aspx)