# using application role of sql server2005 express in multiple forms in c#

Tags: c#, .net, role

I have a C# .net winforms application with two forms which connects to sql express using connection string.

form1 connects to sql with trusted connection. connection string is given in the app.config file.

now, a button on form1 is clicked which changes the connection to application role credentials.

now, form2 opens & it has a button which when clicked needs to create a database using the application role settings.

so how do i use the application role settings created in form1 into form2. because to execute the database creation query the Form2 needs a new connection object.

So, do i have to add another app.config file or what else?

------------------------EDITED----------------------------------------------------

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             //new code for using conenction string from app.config file added 
                //  Read appSettings
                    string title = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ApplicationTitle"];
                    string connectString =
                    ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
                    conn.ConnectionString = connectString;
           //new code ends

        conn.Open();
        string setapprole = "sp_setapprole 'my_app' , 'app_pass' ";
        SqlCommand cmd_app = new SqlCommand(setapprole, conn);
        SqlDataReader approle_reader = cmd_app.ExecuteReader();
        approle_reader.Close();

        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }

}
```

--------------------------------FORM2.CS------------------------------

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   //how to connect to the database, 
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        string query = "create database new_db";
         //I WANT TO USE the conn object here, 
          //& want the connection to use the application role
         // which was set in Form1.cs 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn); 
        SqlDataReader createdb = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    }
}
```

---------------EDITED-1----------------------------------

my app.config file :

`xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"

configuration

appSettings
    add key="ApplicationTitle" value="Setup Database , Tables and Permissions" 
    add key="ConnectionString"
         value="Server=localhost; Trusted_Connection=true" 
  appSettings

configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to modify the connection parameters and then open a new connection to the DB.

**EDIT**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TODO;Initial Catalog=TODO;Integrated Security=True");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_setapprole 'my_app' , 'app_pass' ", conn))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            // The application role is set and remains active until the user disconnects

            Form2 f2 = new Form2(conn);
            f2.Show();
        }
    }

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        //how to connect to the database, 
        public Form2(SqlConnection conn)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.conn = conn;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("create database new_db", conn))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Important to close the DB connection (at which point the approle becomes inactive)
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: @tzup, sir , should connection pooling be used for this task?

Comment: @tzup, does every form in c#.net needs a new connection to be established with the sql databases?

Comment: @sqlchild, No, usually you open a DB connection, run a query and then close the connection. In other words, don't keep the DB connection open while your app is running.

Comment: @tzup, so how shall i share the same application role for multiple forms. can you help me out with the exact code.

Comment: @sqlchild, Please provide the code that you already have first. At least, the relevant parts so that I can get a better idea.

Comment: @sqlchild, in my edited portion is a potential (not so elegant) solution. Hope this helps!

Comment: @tzup : sir, using my application the users would continuously insert data in the database, so for this i need the connection to the database to remain opened continuously until the application is closed, so in this case shall i use dataset, because datasets use disconnected environment?

Comment: @tzup : in datasets , when the user would click the save button , then will the connection needs to be opened ? so how would i do this please help. actually my application,would be used for managing sales of a shop, so users would continuously keep on inserting data, as an item is sold they would insert its Quantity Sold, MRP etc. so in this case how do manage with the connection to the database?

Comment: @tzup, sir in the code you have given , you haven't using app.config file. but if i want to use it then?

Comment: @tzup , have updated my question , mentioning the app.config file., in this case also, the code would be same?

Comment: @sqlchild, Don't keep the DB connection open. The recommended aproach is to open/run query/close, no matter how many operations you have, so don't keep the connection open as long as your app is running. Regarding the app.config, I'm not sure that I understand. Perhaps another question would be a better place to discuss this matter.