# logins , users, permissions in sql express 2005 , with diagram , flowchart

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, diagram, flowchart

[image]

I want to create logins & users for my c#.net winforms application which uses sql server 2005 express .& upto my knowledge i have built these steps.

So , I want to ask that are these steps correct or am i making a lot of mistakes.

Also, if am missing any step then please add new steps.
Also, in the last step, what should i do, do i have to grant permissions to both ,USERS & SCHEMA, OR to only USER, OR to only SCHEMA.

I am seeking improvements in this model or a new model if anybody can provide. Would be a great help.

I want to GRANT & DENY permissions of DATABASE LEVEL such as CREATE, DROP, ALTER DATABASE ;  of TABLE LEVEL such as INSERT , DELETE, ALTER, UPDATE & of COLUMN LEVEL.

Also, is creation of schema necessary?

As far as i know: 
CREATION OF LOGIN is necessary
CREATION OF USER for the above created login is necessary
CREATION OF SCHEMA is or is not necessary? i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm changing my whole answer. I really think it's not a good idea to grant uses direct login access to your db. The DB is not the right "choke point" for permissions. Create one user with the total db permissions you will need. Then grant the users features in your application based on their role in the application (tracked in a table in your database).

There are a lot of problems with creating 1 login per user in your database. A few are 1. Maintainance nightmare 2. Now your users can log in to your db directly if they can get connected to it with Management studio or some other tool.

1. To elaborate . . . create one login for your application. Name it something like *MyApplicationUser*.
2. Create a table in your application to track the roles that each user could be part of. This can also track the features they are allowed to have in your application (though probably in a different table)
3. When the user starts the application, the application is opend using the same db credentials (*MyApplicationUser*)
4. Now you know who the user is (based on NTID, or application login), and you can give them the features that are appropriate to them in the application)

Comment: @Richard DesLonde, i am building c#.net winform application , not a web application

Comment: Sorry, I revised my answer. :-)

Comment: @Richard DesLonde , sir, i am making a simple winform application which will use sql server, it will only have a single database. it will be used by 3 users,U1,U2,U3. Users U2,U3 will only INSERT data in the sql database. Sql server will be installed only one one machine which will be used by U1. U1 CAN Delete, Alter, Update also. How do i do this? please help me out with the code? All 3 machines are on LAN.

Comment: Here's what I would do. 1. Create a login (_MyApplicationUSer_) in the database that can _INSERT_, _DELETE_, and _UPDATE_. 2. Use this login as your application's db login connection for all users. 3. Then create a table (_UserFeatures_) in your db with columns like this _UserID_, _Feature_. U1 will get 3 records, like this (U1,DELETE), (U1,INSERT), (U1,UPDATE). U2 and U3 will only get 1 record each like this (U2,INSERT), (U3,INSERT). Now, when your user opens the application, get their NT ID. Now you know who is logged in, and based on your table _UserFeatures_, you know what they are ...

Comment: ...allowed to do. Now in your application you can all and disallow their actions based on their features in _UserFeatures_. Does this make sense. So for instance, if you have a form where a user could potentially be able to delete something, you would first check if that user has the DELETE feature (by checking _UserFeatures_). If they don't have that feature, you can disable the ability to delete anything in that form for that user. Make sense?