# Using logins, users, permissions in SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: sql, authentication, sql-server-2005-express

I connected to SQL Server with Windows Authentication (Admin).

Then, I created a login for my SQL Server 2005 Express as:

```
CREATE LOGIN bob WITH PASSWORD = 'bobpass'.
```

Now, I closed SQL Server & then again opened it & this time I connected it with the login 'bob'.

Now, I executed this : `SELECT CURRENT_USER.`

It gave the output :    guest

Why so?

Is this because I didn't create any user inside the `bob` login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CURRENT_USER will return a database principal (an user). `bob` is a server principal (a login). If you didn't grant access to any database and you didn't add bob to any builtin server security groups, then he will not have access to any database except master and tempdb. In those two databases, he will be recognized as `guest`. This is the default, you may notice differences from this description if you have something changed in your deployment from a fresh installation (eg. you may discover that `bob` has access to more databases because those databases have enabled `guest`).

So basically you guessed right:`bob` is `guest` because he does not have an explicit database principal (an user) nor is he member of `sysadmin` (in which case he would be `dbo` in every database).

Comment: thanks a lot sir, also, sir if i create a bobuser for the bob login , then can i connect to sql server using username as bobuser

Comment: i also have a question on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117029/logins-users-permissions-in-sql-express-2005-with-diagram-flowchart

Comment: sir, if i give sysadmin role to bob, then he would be dbo of all databases, means a user would be automatically created under login bob, named as dbo?

Comment: when a login is created , then is a user also created automatically for that login ?